# I've compiled all my tracking data but when I go to default to add the object, the video isn't in the background

Tags: tracking

I'm tracking a child on a swing on the video editing window and clicked the *Setup Tracking Motion* button in the *Solve* tab to ready the footage to edited with 3D objects in Default.

But lo an  behold, every time I try to go to default, the video doesn't appear.

What can I do? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Solving the scene doesn't automatically set the image as background, nor does it prepare the necessary nodes in the compositor to render the scene over the video background.

Once you solve the scene press:

Set as Background.

[image]

And Setup Tracking Scene

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add your video as a background image in 3D viewport and use **Movie Clip**.

[image]